# Elasticsearch runtime fields performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm in my journey learning Elasticsearch & come across "Runtime Fields"

As far as I know, we can use runtime fields for filtering data just like a normal field. This brings me to a question that "How runtime fields are calculated during a search request?"

Will all runtime fields of an index will be calculated for all the documents & after that, the filter phase happen? I know this might have an effect to search performance but to what extend?

Answer (score 1):

tldr - yes, there's a cost to these. they are all calculated at search time and then filters etc are run on them

generally we recommend doing the "work" involved in making the values for these sorts of things up front. do it via an ingest pipeline or something like that. that means when you query, the "work" has been done and response are as quick as possible. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/runtime.html#runtime-compromises goes into some of this

ultimately, comparing runtime to index time would really need to be done with your data and setup